# vim command mode g++ doesn't pick the bash alias

Tags: normal-mode, bash

I have g++ alias defined in my `.bashrc` file as

```
alias g++='g++ -Wall -DLOCAL=1'
```

I am invoking following command from vim command/normal mode to compile a program -

```
!g++ %
```

The issue is, this command is working, but this is not picking the alias that's defined in bashrc file. It appears vim is invoking the original g++. To be precise, it looks like vim is not executing the command in current shell/env setup.

When I run `g++ file.cpp` from bash commandline the alias is being picked up correctly.

Ofcourse I can dump the entire required command in the command mode, but I would like vim to pickup the alias defined in `.bashrc` file.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You might be interested in `:make` and `'makeprg'`